# How can I add items to a list<T> from form input in a controller without using views? ASP.NET MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller

I have a list of type

I am generating html in the browser on submit

I need the submitted information to be added to the list

Answer (score 0):

How can you save data from that is from view and not use view question is little vague can you be more specific  , if you want to add the incoming model/view data to controller to list just initialize the list add it and do any data manipulation  if needed as per requirement  and save it either to dB or as per your requirement.